# Spring using different DataSource that depends on user

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authorization, datasource

I have web application and i use Spring MVC. Now i'd like to add to different dataSources for administrator and for simple user. So my application should connect through anonymous user to DB, that can only select from tables and insert into some tables. But when user authorize himself by admin - application should change user and password on DB connection and connect with root authorities to DB. Is it possible to do this with spring 3.0.5?

Comment: You can, of course, configure multiple datasources and then include logic in your application that chooses one based on the authorization level of the user. Is that what you want or do want Spring to automatically route calls to a particular datasource or something like that?

Comment: Yes i'd like automatically way. Could you please give me some material or example of how can i change dataSource in runtime? I thought that Spring Security could do that, but i didn't find any information about it.

Comment: Couldn't you just have a `dao` class specifically for admin-related activities with the appropriate `datasource` autowired into it? Then the `dao` class could be autowired into the appropriate controllers, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter
```

you can set the credentials on the Datasource via setCredentialsForCurrentThread() method in the login filter, for example.

Comment: Great! So as you said i declare this bean in AppContext then in my CustomAuthenticationManager when user or admin login i will get this datasource using @Autowire and set admin password to it. But i have a question: Does this datasource - session bean or singleton? Cause i will use it in jdbcTemplate. Or should i declare this datasource with session scope?

Comment: Use a singleton datasource and lets  the connection pool to handle the per user pooled connections.